# Writing Data to an OutputStream with Swift 5+

Tags: swift, stream, outputstream, binary-data, swift5

This code used to be fine (in the sense that the compiler didn't complain):

```
extension OutputStream {
    func write(_ data: Data) -> Int {
        return data.withUnsafeBytes { pointer in
            return self.write(pointer, maxLength: data.count)
        }
    }
}
```

Since Swift 5.0, this produces a warning:

> Warning: 'withUnsafeBytes' is deprecated: use `withUnsafeBytes<R>(_: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> R) rethrows -> R` instead

I tried using the proposed method but I can't seem to wrangle the `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` into the `UnsafePointer<UInt8>` that `OutputStream.write` ultimately requires.

How can I write this function in a non-deprecated way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is to use `bindMemory` function:

```
func write(_ data: Data) -> Int {
    return data.withUnsafeBytes({ (rawBufferPointer: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) -> Int in
        let bufferPointer = rawBufferPointer.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self)
        return self.write(bufferPointer.baseAddress!, maxLength: data.count)
    })
}
```

While this works with Swift 5.0, there are apparently some issues; see [a related forum discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-use-data-withunsafebytes-in-a-well-defined-manner/12811).