# Error message: Ambiguous reference to member 'withUnsafeBytes'

Tags: swift

I'm confused on how to fix this code.

I'm sending data from the swift app to a python socket server running on a raspberry pi, and I keep getting this error message. I'm using this tutorial: http://studyswift.blogspot.com/2016/03/sending-rsa-encrypted-message-from-ios_3.html

```swift
  //network vars
    var inStream : InputStream?
    var outStream: OutputStream?

    //recieved data
    //var buffer = [UInt8](count: 2000, repeatedValue: 0)
    var inStreamLength: Int!
    var keyString = ""

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }

        label1.text = String(format:"%f", locValue.latitude)
        label2.text = String(format:"%f", locValue.longitude)

        func getKey() {
            let data: Data = "Client: OK".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            outStream?.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.withUnsafeBytes), maxLength: data.length)   
        }
```

I'm getting an error message on outStream?.write(...)
"Ambiguous reference to member 'withUnsafeBytes'"

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55829812/writing-data-to-an-outputstream-with-swift-5.

Comment: It still doesn't work, I'm getting more errors